# What can I use to display VPN instance instead of stelnet?

Tags: vpn, ssh, huawei

How can ı connect VPN service with use ssh in Huawei Atn980c ? Which command? I researched but i didnt different command. I found only this command; stelnet x.x.x.x (VPN instance) (service name) (port name)
My customer asked to me.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the Huawei's documentation and I see that stelnet command is the ssh client implementation on huawei devices. Here is the reference: (https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/es/doc/EDOC1100089358)

[image]